# Error using xlsread (line 247) Error registering event(s), Advise failed

Tags: excel, matlab, optimization, particle-swarm

I'm running a Particle Swarm Optimization on MATLAB and I use excel files for my inputs (temperature, time, demand, etc).

I am using Matlab R2014a, Windows7, MS office 2013

My input files are imported like:

```
t=xlsread('inputs.xls','Hours');
T=xlsread('inputs.xls','Temperature');
V=xlsread('inputs.xls','Wind');
Gtotal_tilted=xlsread('inputs.xls','Solar');
Pload=xlsread('inputs.xls','Demand');
```

However, when I increased the population number and the iteration number of my code for better results I get at some point the following error:

```
Error using xlsread (line 247)

Error registering event(s), Advise failed

Error in ConstraintFinal (line 10)
Pload=xlsread('inputs.xls','Demand');

Error in funcFinal (line 16)
[LCOE,CAPEX] = ConstraintFinal(N_wec, N_pv, Nbat);

Error in PSOGraph_Final (line 45)
        fitness(j) = funcFinal(x(:,j),scale_factor);
```

Comment: From the MATLAB Central posts on the subject it seems like the issue arises with multiple repeated `xlsread` or `xlswrite` calls. Try adding a pause in between each call, [as suggested here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/84277-using-xlswrite-with-excel-2013), to give Excel enough time to close and clear out of memory.

Comment: Why you should read/write files during the optimization? Just load the data at the beginning and write/save the result at the end. Even, you have to write the data in between, you can do it as `mat` files with better performance.